# Getting "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream." Error

Tags: c#, file, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

"Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream." is pointing towards the line of codes:

```
var fileStream = storage.OpenFile(item.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
```

in the codes below:

```
private void OnReadSelected()
            {
                IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                List<FileItem> readItems = new List<FileItem>();
                foreach (var item in Files)
                {
                    if (item.IsChecked)
                        if (storage.FileExists(item.FileName))
                        {
                            storage.DeleteFile(item.FileName);
                            readItems.Add(item);
                        }
                }
                 foreach (var item in readItems)
                     using (var fileStream = storage.OpenFile(item.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                     {
                         using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                         {
                             item.FileName = reader.ReadLine();
                             item.FileText1 = reader.ReadLine();

                             item.RdbText1 = reader.ReadLine();

                         }
                     }
            }
```

Am I to use another derivative besides StreamReader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (var item in Files)
{
    if (item.IsChecked)
        if (storage.FileExists(item.FileName))
        {
           storage.DeleteFile(item.FileName);
           readItems.Add(item);
        }
}
```

You have used this code to delete some files from the store depending upon the condition **if(item.IsChecked)**. And you are adding those items to the **readItems** collection.
But in this code

```
foreach (var item in readItems)
                     using (var fileStream = storage.OpenFile(item.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                     {
                         using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                         {
                             item.FileName = reader.ReadLine();
                             item.FileText1 = reader.ReadLine();
                             item.RdbText1 = reader.ReadLine();
                         }
                     }
```

you are trying to open the files which you have just deleted from the store.

So, you are getting the exception ***Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream*** as the files doesn't exist in the store.